# Laravel 5.4 - Artisan make:controller XxxController --resource --model=Xxx not identifying Model driectory genereted by reliese/laravel

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-artisan

I have a database that already is in use when I started a new API in **Laravel 5.4**.

For this reason, instead of use **Migrations**, I have used [reliese/laravel](https://github.com/reliese/laravel) to generate the **Models** from my database.

The point is that reliese have created models inside `app/Models/`. So I have a table that was converted into `app/Models/City.php` for example.

So when I try to create a **Controller** using **Artisan** like this:

```
php artisan make:controller CityController --resource --model=City
```

I get this error:

```
A App\City model does not exist. Do you want to generate it? (yes/no) [yes]:
```

Because **Artisan** is searching the Model City.php inside app/ folder.

Is there a way to make **Artisan** to point to `app/Models` instead?

Comment: php artisan make:controller CityController --resource --model=app\City

Answer (score 1):

This is more elegant

```
php artisan make:controller CityController --resource --model=Models/City
```

Answer (score 0):

I will share here what I did:

```
php artisan make:controller CityController --resource --model=Models\\City

Controller created successfully.
```

I had to use double backslash **"\"** without the `app\` folder.

Comment: How can I create controllers for all the models in that folder?

Comment: programatically speaking I would need to check. But you can do one by one. The only point here is that you need to specify the path --model=Models\\ ...